# Status bar is changing with the latest Xcode build while scrolling in table view -> tab view -> navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode

History: My project has been last released more than a year ago with xcode 11 build. It has been in maintenance stage. Due a urgent bug, we resolved it and while releasing we came to know apple forced people to use xcode 14 and latest sdk etc. We shifted to latest versions of all. We faced many build errors as many of our files are writtern in objc . We resolved them. (mostly by adding pods and objc/objc members tag). But are facing a weird issue which was not available in the previous ones.

Issue: We have 3 vc , A (objc,large tableview need to scroll, white) , B (swift, black), C (Swift, white), They are integrated into a tab view T(objective c). This tabview has been embeded in custom navigation controller N which inherits UINavigationcontroller. We have set View Controller - based status bar appearance - YES and override preferedStatusBarStyle in every child view controllers. Ww faced the same issue in nav bar. but it seems well behaved better after chaning bartintcolor to backgroundColor. No luck with statusbar.
After running the app there is a small portion of view outside the tableview which was not available in previous build.
For example, in A it is supposed to be white, but it comes black, after scrolling a little (that small portion) we get white.

is there anything changed in last year. Any help would be much appreciated.

Fixed nav bar partically by changing tint color to background color.